# Is it possible to have pointer to struct variable that is inside another struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
struct S1 {
    int a;
};

struct S2 {
    int b;
    S1 s;
};

int S2::*ptrB = &S2::b; // pointer to data member 'b'
int S2::*ptrA = ?       // pointer to data member 'a'
```

Is it possible to have member pointer to `a` member variable?

EDIT:

Many people asked why I need this. I have many duplicated code lines like this:

```
object.get("struct1.struct2.var1", &record.struct2.var1);
object.get("struct1.struct3.var1", &record.struct3.var1);

object.get("struct1.struct2.var1", &record2.struct2.var1);
object.get("struct1.struct3.var1", &record2.struct3.var1);
```

My goal is to create list of string and member pointers and then iterate over this list.

Comment: I wonder why somebody would want that

Comment: Just curious, what exactly is your use case for this?

Comment: @Slava answered in edit

Comment: The answer is no to the code you put, since in your struct S2, s is not a pointer of an S1 struct, there is no way you can track it outside the scope of S2.  
However the following code will work:

    struct S1 {
        int a;
    };
    
    struct S2 {
        int b;
        S1 *s;
    };

...//some code to create an S2 called S2_instance that contains a valid s1 pointer

    (S2_instance->s)->a
this will give back the a you store in your S1